# Dynamically loading a class file with a non default package and no nested folders

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I am writing a curriculum project for students new to Java. It has a folder structure as so.

```
myjar.jar
solutions/my/really/long/package/MySolution.class
```

I got it so the jar can load all classes in the solutions/my/really/long/package/ directory.
by adding 'solutions/' to the classpath.

My question is if it is possible to set it up so there is no long nested folders for the package without using the default package.

The resulting structure would be

```
myjar.jar
solutions/MySolution.class
```

But the MySolution class would not have a default package.

Comment: What's wrong with the class files in their appropriate package directory structure?

Comment: It works, just can be a hassle, especially for a new programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could write your own classloader. That would probably do the trick - but it's really not a nice thing to do, and in particular your students would then get used to something which wouldn't work in the real world.

Why not just use a short package name?

Comment: Or custom URLStreamHandler (like the jar protocol). But, yes, why?